# Wordpress change wp_nav_menu walker with a custom one

Tags: navigation, walker

I have a downloaded theme and it where the wp_nav_menu is created it looks something like this:

```
<div class="nv-nav-wrap">
    <div role="navigation" class="<?php echo esc_attr( join( ' ', $container_classes ) ); ?>"
            aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Primary Menu', 'neve' ); ?>">

        <?php
        echo wp_nav_menu(
            [
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'menu_id'        => $menu_id,
                'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu-ul nav-ul' . $additional_menu_class,
                'container'      => 'ul',
                'walker'         => '\Neve\Views\Nav_Walker',
                'fallback_cb'    => '\Neve\Views\Nav_Walker::fallback',
                'echo'           => false,
            ]
        );
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've created a child theme and I want to change the walker of the wp_nav_menu. How can I do that?
The new walker's name is  "Aria walker Nav menu" (just for reference)

I've tried putting this in functions.php in the child theme:

```
    wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'primary',
      'container'      => false,
      'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu-ul nav-ul',
      'walker'         => new Aria_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
      'items_wrap'     => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    ) );
```

But it creates a whole new menu. How do I just replace the walker for the original one in the theme

Comment: you'd need to replace the file the original theme uses to display the menu in your child theme with one that is the same but has your new walker. Unfortunately you did not mention any details of where or how the theme does this so it's not possible to say if this would work or not and which file would need to be changed, or if an alternative method is necessary. `functions.php` is not the place to put `wp_nav_menu` calls, are you familiar with how child themes templates work?

Answer (score 0):

In general you'd [add child substitutions for the relevant templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#adding-template-files) if possible, as Tom mentions in the comments.

Alternately, you can use a [`wp_nav_menu_args` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_args/) hook to swap in your own arguments prior to WordPress retrieving and rendering the menu:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_args', 'wpse406010_primary_nav_menu_args' );

function wpse406010_primary_nav_menu_args( $args ) {
  if( $args[ 'theme_location' ] !== 'primary' || $args[ 'walker' ] !== '\Neve\Views\Nav_Walker' )
    return $args;

  $args[ 'container' ]  = false;
  $args[ 'menu_class' ] = 'primary-menu-ul nav-ul';
  $args[ 'walker' ]     = new Aria_Walker_Nav_Menu();
  $args[ 'items_wrap' ] = '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>';

  return $args;
}
```

Comment: I didn't find a filter called ``wp_get_nav_menu_args`` in the current version of WordPress. Did you mean ``wp_nav_menu_args``?